Sub division numbering

I would like to add subdivision numbering in column C. When I input any number in column D, the corresponding number in column C should be followed by an alphabetical suffix, such as A, B, C, D, etc. Alternatively, column C should contain unique numbers.
=IFNA(IF(MATCH(D6,$AY$5:$AY$15003,0),D6&" "&"A",$AY6),AY6)

It's unclear to me exactly what you want, what determines which letter is added? What do you mean by the alternative unique numbers, that seems like an entirely different question? A clear example of inputs and desired outputs might help clarify the question.

If you insert a table for your data, you could enter this in the first cell of "Ref. no." (clear the cells below first): =@[Split to] & " " & COUNTIF(INDEX([Split to], 1, 1):@[Split to], @[Split to]). Please be aware any changes will affect the suffix.

If you have Excel for Microsoft 365 (to use MAP and LAMBDA), you could try this dynamic array formula:

Adjust the ranges to match your data
Enter the following in the first cell (C5 in the example), clearing the cells below it as the result will 'spill'
For suffix using number, use:
IF(MATCH(split_to, ref_range, 0), split_to & " " & number_suffix, ref_range)

Method:

With MAPping each row, get a running count of items in "Split to" and use it for suffix

=LET(
    ref_range, $AY$5:$AY$15003, split_to, $D$5:$D$15003,
    ref_count, LAMBDA(r,
        IF(INDEX(split_to, r) = "", "",
            SUM(--(INDEX(split_to, 1):INDEX(split_to, r) = INDEX(split_to, r))))
    ),
    number_suffix, MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(split_to)), ref_count),
    note, "TODO: customize letter suffix if range is beyond A-Z",
    letter_suffix, CHAR(CODE("A") + number_suffix - 1),
    ref_no, IFNA(
        IF(MATCH(split_to, ref_range, 0), split_to & " " & letter_suffix, ref_range),
        IF(ISBLANK(ref_range), "", ref_range)),
    ref_no
)



These formulas maybe satisfies your requirements.
C6 cell:  =IF(D6="","",TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,D6, COUNTA(FILTER(D$6:D6,D$6:D6=D6))))
B6 cell:
=IF(D6="","",TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,D6,CHAR(COUNTA(FILTER(D$6:D6,D$6:D6=D6))+64)))

Copy down the formula for the used range.
If characters are used (cell B6) than after Z other non alfabetic characters will follow. So over 26 items you will get weird result.

